# PowerShell pass by reference not working for me

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to make a simple swap function in PowerShell, but passing by reference doesn't seem to work for me.

```
function swap ([ref]$object1, [ref]$object2){
  $tmp = $object1.value
  $object1.value = $object2.value
  $object2.value = $tmp
}

$a = 1
$b = 2
$a, $b
swap ([ref]$a) ,([ref]$b)
$a, $b
```

This SHOULD work, but no...

```
Output:
    1
    2
    1
    2
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Call like this:

```
swap ([ref]$a) ([ref]$b)
```

The mistake of using `,` is described in the [*Common Gotchas* for PowerShell here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/powershell/info).

Answer (score 25):

By the way, PowerShell has a special syntax to swap values, and there isn't a need to use $tmp:

```
$a,$b = $b,$a
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you're calling it wrong. Putting a comma in the call to swap means you're passing an array of them to objects as the first parameter. If you were to correct it...

```
swap ([ref]$a) ([ref]$b)
```

...it would then work.

Comment: You can pass value types by reference.

Comment: @Rynant: You're right. I did it over again and it didn't complain about value types. Not sure what I did different the first time.